# issue with getting multiple images from php form to jquery

Tags: javascript, php, jquery, html, file-upload

I want to upload multiple images at a time. But, I am not getting all the file names in jquery.

HTML:

```
<input name="my_image[]" id="my_file" size="27" type="file" class="inputImage"
title="Upload images" multiple="multiple" />
```

JQUERY:

```
var my_file = new Array();
$('#my_file').each(function(){
    my_file.push($(this).val());
});
alert(my_file);
```

I am getting only 1 file name...

Comment: This is far too incomplete to answer.  What are the value(s) you are putting into the field?  Also, `#my_file` should be an *ID* of a single element, yet you're looking over it (or them) in a `.each` function.

Comment: I am getting file name over there. I mentioned in my question. but, I am getting only 1 file

Comment: Yes, but you didn't tell us if you have multiple inputs.  Your javascript says you do, your html says you don't.  And, if you only have one input, then you should **expect** to only return one file name.  Again, what are you **entering** in the input?